# How to find SQLite db on iPhone 6s Simulator in Macbook?

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am searching for my SQLLite DB in my Simulator.

Based on ActivityMonitor, I am able to get the folder path of my Application.

/Users/MyMacBook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A4170C16-A10B-4B48-9C7B-2A310F68B35F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F6C6772C-021A-4B27-874D-071B402DDBCC/

Though i couldn't find the SQLite database.  I work on VS 2015 Xamarin Project.

How should i find SQLite db on my Simulator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By *default*, most `SQLite` libraries/frameworks will place the Sqlite file in the root of your `.app`.

When you establish your SQLite connection if you are supplying a path and a filename to your SQLite file, then follow that path.

#### Example using `sqlite-net`:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection("StackOverflow.sqlite");
```

#### Location:

```
cd Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
find $PWD -name "StackOverflow.sqlite" -print

/Users/sushi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EB2B821-E86B-4E9A-9814-1BBEF8FF1AA1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/11BE399A-F802-4410-8163-32F5A90EB2FF/SQLiteLocation.app/StackOverflow.sqlite
```

#### Example using `Path.GetTempPath`:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "StackOverflow.sqlite"));
```

#### Location:

```
cd Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
find $PWD -name "StackOverflow.sqlite" -print

/Users/sushi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EB2B821-E86B-4E9A-9814-1BBEF8FF1AA1/data/Containers/Data/Application/EED6E9CE-7437-48DD-904D-5F9D5E8AC78F/tmp/StackOverflow.sqlite
```

Comment: I am testing a Project developed by another resource. I will not be able to do any code change. Is there any way to view the sqlite .. without touching the code

Comment: @goofyui You do not need to modify any code, those were examples of where you might find the SQLite file depending upon how the program names the file and its location. After you have the SQLie file you can open it with any SQLite management tool.

Answer (score 3):

Find the location of sqlite file by using the code in your `appDelegate` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))
}
```

Every time when running the app, your can find the location printed in the Xcode console.

I'm using application [simMagnifier](http://microedition.biz/simMagnifier/index.html) to view the SQLite file

Comment: i downloaded the SimMagnifer and able to see my App listed on it. It says, " This App doesn't support the core data " ..

Comment: Thank you @Arasuvel, I tested with SimMagnifer. It helps. Thank you so much for your help ..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I use to use SimPholders (but it's paid). I found this free open-source alternative called [Open Sim](https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim). It lets you browse the directories of the apps on your simulator. It makes it super easy to locate the sqlite db in your Xamarin App and then you just need a sqlite viewer to open the actual database.

Comment: i installed the SimPholders, how should i configure or view the folder path

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure. Just pick the simulator you deployed to in the menu, and then the app you're wanting.

Comment: i tested with SimPholders and SimMagnifer. I find SimMagnifer is much helpful. Thank you again.

Comment: You can find simMagnifier here: http://www.microedition.biz/simMagnifier/index.html